# Jquery Simple Grid Insert from TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have One TextBox and Add Button.
When i click on Add button. Value Should Added in Grid and with Delete Icon in row.

just want to use Simple Jquery Grid.
Please Help.

Comment: nothing just surf on net to find grid.

Comment: is "grid" equal to table?

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/2014/01/appendgrid-dynamic-table-input-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

if Grid is a table,

check out this : http://jsfiddle.net/hamidlab/C8TT4/

very simple jquery to add and remove row from table. `.remove()` to remove tr and `.append()` to add new tr.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any jquery plugin then you can use jQGrid.js

[http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html][1]

To use this grid accrding to your requirment then you have modify it as it will take data from you form or any input fields.

Or if you want to creat simple custome grid using table then you can use the code

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="inputText" />
<button id="addNew">Add New Row</button>
<table border=1 >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>

            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>

            <td><button>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript :**

```
function createRow(data){
    var newRow = "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+data+"</td>"+
                    "<td><button>Delete</button></td>"+
                "/tr>";    
    return newRow;
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#addNew").on("click", function(){
        var data = $("#inputText").val();
        if(data != ""){
            var row = createRow(data);
        }
        $("table tbody").append(row);
        $("#inputText").val("");
    });
    $("table").on("click", "button", function(){
        var row = $(this).parents("tr");
        if(row){
            row.remove();
        }

    });
});
```